# Executing in background, but limit number of executions

Tags: perl, bash, background-process

I have a program that performs some operations on a specified log file, flushing to the disk multiple times for each execution. I'm calling this program from a perl script, which lets you specify a directory, and I run this program on all files within the directory. This can take a long time because of all the flushes.

I'd like to execute the program and run it in the background, but I don't want the pipeline to be thousands of executions long. This is a snippet:

```
my $command = "program $data >> $log";
myExecute("$command");
```

myExecute basically runs the command using system(), along with some other logging/printing functions. What I want to do is:

```
my $command = "program $data & >> $log";
```

This will obviously create a large pipeline. Is there any way to limit how many background executions are present at a time (preferably using &)? (I'd like to try 2-4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# lets call this script "multi_script.sh"
#
#wait until there are less then 4 instances running
#polling with interval 5 seconds

while [ $( pgrep -c program ) -gt 4 ]; do sleep 5; done

/path/to/program "$1" &
```

Now call it like this:

```
my $command = "multi_script.sh $data" >> $log;
```

Your perl script will wait if the bash script waits.

**positives:**
If a process crashes it will be replaced (the data goes, of course, unprocessed)

**Drawbacks:**
It is important for your perl script to wait a moment between starting instances
(maybe a sleep period of a second)
 because of the latency between invoking the script and passing the while loop test. If you spawn them too quickly (system spamming) you will end up with much more processes than you bargained for.

Comment: Thanks Thom. This looks very promising. Forgive me though, as I can't completely understand the code that you proposed.

I looked up the pgrep manual, and I don't see a -c flag available. Did you mean for this to be -f? I also don't understand the search string you used: ${PROGRAM##*/}. Sorry if I'm a little bit slow, but could you please explain this to me?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand that you are trying to get the count now, so I piped to 'wc -l'. I'm still not understanding the ${PROGRAM##*/} part though, but otherwise I implemented with just 'pgrep PROGRAM | wc -l' and it's working as expected. One problem that I will run into though is that I often run the perl script on multiple directories. I don't believe that this will allow me to do so anymore, since it's looking for any process with the program name in it.

Comment: @user3006471, `pgrep -c` counts the number of matching instances. Indeed if your `pgrep` does not have a -c option, then pipe it to `wc -l` Nevermind the ${PROGRAM##*/} thing. I made an error here. I have already corrected it

Comment: Running the script on multiple directories is possible. Can you elaborate a bit on why that would be a problem ?

Comment: Thanks again! Basically what I want to do is run my perl script on multiple directories simultaneously. For example, if I want to delete directory A on partition 1 and directory B on partition 2, I'd normally have 2 terminal windows open both running my Perl script. However, since pgrep is checking for just the program name that the perl script calls, then the 4 background processes that were originally intended for 1 instance of the perl script will be split between 2 instances now, etc.

Comment: Yes one script will probably starve the other indeed. When, in your perl script, your System() call finishes, it kills the shell and the running programs will lose their parent and are adopted by `init` so it will be impossible to trace by $PPID who was the parent. If you can pipe your data tot System() -instead of repeatedly calling System()- it would be possible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change

```
my $command = "program $data & >> $log";
```

into

```
my $command = "cat $data >>/path/to/datafile";
```

(or even better: append $data to /path/to/datafile directly from perl )
And when your script is finished that the last line will be:

```
System("/path/to/quadslotscript.sh");
```

then I have the script `quadslotscript.sh` here:

1. 4 execution slots are started and stay until the end
2. all slots get input from the same datafile
3. when a slot is ready with processing it will read a new entry to process
   until the datafile/queue is empty
4. no processtable lookup during execution, only when all work is done.

the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#use the datafile as a queue where all processes get their input
exec 3< "/path/to/datafile"

#4 seperate processes 
while read -u 3 DATA; do "/path/to/program $DATA" >>$log; done &
while read -u 3 DATA; do "/path/to/program $DATA" >>$log; done &
while read -u 3 DATA; do "/path/to/program $DATA" >>$log; done &
while read -u 3 DATA; do "/path/to/program $DATA" >>$log; done &

#only exit when 100% sure that all processes ended
while pgrep "program" &>"/dev/null" ; do wait ; done
```